# Suppressing or avoiding Warning CA2214

Tags: c#, fxcop

I have a situation where I create an object called `EntryEvent` from data I receive. That data has to be parsed. The base event is supposed to kick off parsing of the data that was received through the constructor, and given to the object. The subtype knows how to pars that specific data set. Now, when compiling said code, I get the warning CA2214, that it contains a call chain to a virtual method. While it may be bad to have unforseen consequences, I do not know how to get the required behavior: Parse the received event without having to call an additional "Parse" method from the outside.

The Code in question is:

```
public abstract class BaseEvent
{
    protected BaseEvent(object stuff)
    {
        this.ParseEvent();
    }

    protected abstract void ParseEvent();
}

public class EntryEvent : BaseEvent
{
    public EntryEvent( object stuff )
        : base( stuff )
    {
    }

    protected override void ParseEvent()
    {
        // Parse event
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us more context? There are various ways of approaching this which wouldn't cause the problem, but which approach is best will depend on context. Is it reasonable to imagine a subclass which *doesn't* need to override `ParseEvent`? Could each subclass actually have a static method which was given the data, parse it and then call constructors which took the already-parsed data?

Comment: In the code in your question, `ParseEvent()` could be non-virtual, defined only for `EntryEvent`, and called from `EntryEvent`'s constructor directly. If that isn't possible for your real code, can you update your question to better illustrate the scenario you're dealing with?

Comment: @JonSkeet The event comes from an external source. Every Subclass needs to override, as every subclass needs to do their own parsing. The base class holds general data each event supplies. What I intended was to force the implementer of a particular event to implement the parser, while not forcing him to actually call it. What I wanted to avoid was giving the implementer (even if it was me) the option to just randomly name the parsing method, be it static or not, but maybe I'm overanalyzing it.

Comment: @private_meta: Would it ever make sense to construct an event *without* parsing anything, even if that would be primarily for testing? It's not clear whether parsing is really *inherent* in the existence of an event object, or whether it's just what *typically* happens. Consider making constructors (even if they're just private/protected) which take the raw data, rather than doing the parsing *in* the constructor. I can give an example if that would be useful.

Comment: @JonSkeet The Data supplied in the constructor is a handle to fetch event data from a device through a c++ device library, so the intention was not having to do the device handling outside of the event.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how that answers my question, but never mind.

Comment: Then I did not understand what you meant, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MSDN (emphasis is mine):

> When a virtual method is called, the actual type that executes the method is not selected until run time. When a constructor calls a virtual method, **it is possible that the constructor for the instance that invokes the method has not executed**.

So in my opinion you have these options (at least):

1) Do not disable that warning but suppress that message for your specific class(es) documenting its intended behavior (assuming you take extra care to deal with such scenario). It's not so bad if it's limited to few classes in a very controlled environment (after all...warnings are not errors and they may be ignored).

2) Remove that virtual method call from base class constructor but leave `abstract` method declaration there. Developers will have to implement such method and to call it in constructor they will need to mark their classes as `sealed`. Finally add somewhere in class/method documentation that that method must be called inside their constructor and their class must be `sealed` to do so. 
They can *forget* that call but you may add (for `DEBUG` builds) a check when properties or methods are accessed (for example forcing, as part of class interface, to set a specific flag). If they forget to set the flag or they forget to call the method then an exception will be raised (*"This object has not been built, ParseEvent() must be called in derived classes constructor."*).

I don't like this method very much because it adds extra complexity but if your class hierarchy is too big (then you feel you can't use #1) or lazy initialization (described in #3) is not applicable then it may be a *working* solution. I'd also consider to change design to introduce a factory method that will invoke ParseEvent() for each fully constructed object.

3) Change little bit your design: defer parsing to when it's needed. For example:

```
public abstract class BaseEvent
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp
    {
        get
        {
            if (_timestamp == null)
                ParseEvent();

            return _timestamp.Value;
        }
        protected set { _timestamp = value; }
    }

    protected BaseEvent(object stuff)
    {
    }

    protected abstract void ParseEvent();

    private DateTime? _timestamp;
}
```

Last example is only for illustration purposes, you may want to use `Lazy<T>` to do same task in a more coincise, clear and thread-safe way. Of course in reality you'll have more fields/properties and probably parsing will provide all values in one shot (then you just need a flag, no need for `Nullable`/special value on each field) This is approach I'd prefer even if it's more verbose.

Comment: Thanks. as for 3), lazy loading is not an option, as the data might be unavailable from the source by the time it is needed. Of course I would like to avoid 1) as I see the potential problems. 2) seems to be a valid compromise, especially combining documentation with the abstract method a developer HAS to implement. I just wanted to avoid the developer of a subclass being able to forget or ignore something.

Comment: @private_meta with 2) developer may forget to call ParseEvent() in his classes constructor. His fault but you may do some checks when accessing properties (at least in DEBUG builds). Maybe a factory class and a Parse() method to be called by that...)